# What is the KQL syntax to filter by owstaxId managed properties in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, enterprise-search, taxonomy, kql

My understanding of how to use KQL to query against the automatically created managed properties which have the form of owstaxIdProperty, that is that to query for all items with a given term, the syntax is, based on [this post by Mikael Svenson](http://www.techmikael.com/2014/03/s15e01-kql-basics.html):

```
owstaxIdProperty:"GP0|#c8a43f13-5ea1-45f2-b46d-3a1986a1cbd7"
```

However, when I try to enter a similar query through the query to the results.aspx page by entering a url similar to (with the # encoded as %23):

```
/Search/Pages/results.aspx?k=owsTaxIdProperty:"GP0|%23c8a43f13-5ea1-45f2-b46d-3a1986a1cbd7"
```

I obtain no results and a message as in the image below, which suggests to me that the query is getting through

[image]

If I write the query just as `Property:TermLabel`, the query works and the expected results are returned but I think this could be inaccurate if you have duplicated term labels, as I do

[This question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112568) is similar but I suspect that the poster is using SharePoint 2013, rather than 2010

Another possibility is that I should be using the WssId instead of the termGuid, as is suggested in an MSDN post on "Querying on Managed Metadata Field Values in SharePoint Server 2010 (ECM)" (sorry, I can't post more than two links)

Has anyone had success with similar queries using SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Link to mentioned MSDN post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, used the following syntax in search result source 
`{|owstaxIdTaxKeyword:learning}` to filter results that are tagged with enterprise keyword "learning".

You can create a result source in search site and use the source id in the search query url like `/Search/Pages/results.aspx?sourceid=guid`